# How to add empty line between rules when making CSS from SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I have a simple `scss` file:

```scss
.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0;

  &-title {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  &-detail {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

When I compile it to `css`, the output file looks fine:

```css
.slogan {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
} 
.slogan-title {  <--- Expected empty line before rule
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.slogan-detail {  <--- Expected empty line before rule
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

But there are a couple of errors from `stylelint`
*Expected empty line before at-rule (at-rule-empty-line-before)*
and code must meet linter requirements.

I am running the compiler with the `watch` option while developing,
`npx sass scss:css  --watch --no-source-map`

So, the question is: is it possible to configure a sass compiler to make the output css file and preserve the empty line between the rules?

Comment: Curious why you’re linting the output. Code style rules are for developers, for consistency and readability. Why do you care about the formatting details in the compiled output?

Comment: @ray is making a good point here.

Answer (score 1):

There are open-source SASS compilers based on JavaScript. Adding a simple snippet of code resembling to this should work for you.

```
function addCSSLine(css){
    let cssWithoutLine = `${css}`;
    let cssWithLine = cssWithoutLine.replace(/}/g, `}\n`);
    console.log(cssWithLine);
}

addCSSLine(`ADD YOUR CSS HERE`);
```